# How do I set up libcurl in Code::Blocks correctly?

Tags: c, dll, codeblocks, libcurl, mingw32

I downloaded the latest version [curl-8.0.1.zip](https://curl.se/download.html) and unzipped it. I then ran the command `mingw32-make mingw32` in the root directory of the `libcurl` library to build and compile the library.

I went over to Code::Blocks, then in `Settings -> Compiler... -> Linker Settings`, I added the file `../lib/libcurl.dll.a`. And then in `Search directories` added the directory `../include` to `Compiler` and `Resource compiler`, and added `../lib` to `Linker`.

This is what I got:

[image: I got this error]

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to place `libcurl.dll` in the directory with the executable file.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you! It works. But, do I need to copy it in the `Release`/`Debug` folder every time I create a new project?

Comment: Yes, and maybe no. The way Windows searches for dll files can be confusing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order If you use it often and all of your projects use the same version you could put it in a directory in your path and that will usually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. All I needed to do was add the directory of `libcurl.dll` to the system `PATH` and restart Code::Blocks.